# select more fields to avoid select distinct

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, select

Today I saw a tutorial and it said "to avoid select Distinct, select more fields to create unique results",i wonder what's the deeper meaning of this sentence, why select more fields can create unique result than distinct?

```
select distinct FirstName, LastName, address from Users;(bad)

select FirstName, LastName, address, birth, state, work from Users;(good)
```

thanks for your explanation!!

tutorial from-https://www.sisense.com/blog/8-ways-fine-tune-sql-queries-production-databases/

Comment: I suspect the context in which this statement is made may make sense but in isolation it's pure nonsense.

Comment: Without context it is difficult to provide useful guidance. IMO that statement makes little sense as a suggestion for a good habit or best practice. Your goal should generally be to select columns that you **need** and no more.

Comment: sorry about that ,here is the tutorial——https://www.sisense.com/blog/8-ways-fine-tune-sql-queries-production-databases/

Comment: I think they just mean that if you select just firstname and state, you're going to get a lot of Johns in California, and the way people sometimes eliminate those "duplicates" is to slap distinct on the front. If you include more columns, like address, then it's clear they weren't duplicates at all, and the distinct wasn't necessary. (But, maybe you could ask them what they meant, we didn't write that tutorial so I'm not sure we could provide a better answer.)

Comment: Distinct does have it's place and should be used appropriately - what the link is saying is that distinct may be inappropriate in the example on the other hand I could see a case for identifying distinct in the first query

Comment: So I think maybe it  should depends on the different situation; if we select easily repeatable columns then we may need to select more values to add uniqueness.

Comment: It's a performance issue, but I don't think it matters much until your result set is multiple millions of rows of data from which you now have to run again through "DISTINCT."  And even then you don't necessarily need more `fields` as more `where clause` conditions.  Further, if you have a result set that contains so many rows that it becomes a performance issue, I'd question the criteria.